# Pylint shows "Crash ``module 'isort' has no attribute 'SortImports'``" on every file at row 1 column 1?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I enabled PyLint on Visual Studio Code. My Python version is 3.6.13.

However, it shows the following lint error on every file.

> Fatal error while checking 'c:\Users\xxx\source\yyy\exceptions.py'. Please open an issue in our bug tracker so we address this. There is a pre-filled template that you can use in 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\pylint\pylint\Cache\pylint-crash-2022-01-12-09.txt'.pylint(fatal)

````
Issue title:
Crash ``module 'isort' has no attribute 'SortImports'`` (if possible, be more specific about what made pylint crash)
Content:
When parsing the following file:



```python
'''Custom exceptions'''

class NameException(Exception):
    '''Name Exception'''

```

pylint crashed with a ``AttributeError`` and with the following stacktrace:
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylint\lint\pylinter.py", line 1034, in _check_files
    self._check_file(get_ast, check_astroid_module, file)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylint\lint\pylinter.py", line 1069, in _check_file
    check_astroid_module(ast_node)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylint\lint\pylinter.py", line 1204, in check_astroid_module
    ast_node, walker, rawcheckers, tokencheckers
  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylint\lint\pylinter.py", line 1250, in _check_astroid_module
    walker.walk(node)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylint\utils\ast_walker.py", line 77, in walk
    callback(astroid)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylint\checkers\imports.py", line 562, in leave_module
    std_imports, ext_imports, loc_imports = self._check_imports_order(node)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylint\checkers\imports.py", line 725, in _check_imports_order
    isort_driver = IsortDriver(self.config)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylint\utils\utils.py", line 397, in __init__
    self.isort4_obj = isort.SortImports(  # pylint: disable=no-member
AttributeError: module 'isort' has no attribute 'SortImports'
```
````

Comment: Is your isort version between 3 and 4 and did you try to set it up yourself ?

Comment: The `isort` version is 5.10.1. I don't remember if I installed it myself. I probably did.

Answer (score 0):

Your `isort` version seems correct as `pylint` need between [4 and 6 currentely](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/main/setup.cfg#L49). This look like a bug in pylint, could you [open an issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug%2Cneeds+triage&template=BUG-REPORT.yml), please ?